How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{x \left(1 + \sin^2(\ln x)\right)} \, dx$ using $u = \ln{x}$
I tried using the given substitution but it hasn't gotten me far, I just used u-sub by differentiating $u=\ln{x}$, then substituted $u=\ln{x}$ into the denominator and $dx=x du$ on the side. So then I got $\int \frac{1}{1 + \sin^2(u)} \, du$ and then I made the substitution $1+(\sin(x))^2 = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos 2u$ and simplified it. Now I have $2 \int \frac{1}{3 - \cos 2u} \, du$ and I don't know what to do next.

A standard brute-force approach is the Weierstrass substitution of $v = \tan \frac u 2$. Others may come up with more clever alternatives though.

@PrincessEev The clever alternative is making $\tan u$ a new variable.

A short direct calculation could be as follows:
$$\int \frac{du}{1+\sin^2 u}\, du = \int \frac{du}{\cos^2 u + 2\sin^2 u}\, du = \int \frac{1}{1 + 2\tan^2 u}\cdot \frac 1{\cos^2 u}\, du = ...$$
$$...= \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\int \frac{1}{1 + 2\tan^2 u}\, d\left(\sqrt 2 \tan u\right) = \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \arctan\left(\sqrt 2 \tan u\right) + C$$

$$\int{\frac{1}{1 + \sin^2{x}}}dx = \int{\frac{\csc^2{x}}{\csc^2{x} + 1}}dx = \int{\frac{\csc^2{x}}{2 + \cot^2{x}}}dx$$
Now, make use of the sub, $u = \cot{x}, du = -\csc^2{x}\cdot dx$.

$\require{cancel}$
$$\bbox[#f2e6ed,border: 5px dashed #491,20px]{{\Large \int} \frac{1}{x \, \left(1+\sin^2(\ln x)\right)} \mathrm dx = \frac{\arctan \Big(\sqrt 2 \, \tan \left(\ln x \right)\Big)}{\sqrt 2} + c, \qquad c \in \mathbb{R}}$$
The integral comprises the function $\ln$ at the denominator and the function $1/x$ at the numerator. With these assumptions, it is possible to apply the $u$-substitution method by placing the new variable $u=\ln(x)$ so that the derivative ($1/x$ multiplied by the differential $\mathrm dx$) is already present at the numerator, reducing algebraic manipulations to a bare minimum.
We write the integral
$${\Large \int} \frac{1}{x \, \left(1+\sin^2(\ln x)\right)} \mathrm dx$$
in the form
$${\LARGE \int} \frac{1}{\left(1+\sin^2(\bbox[border:2.5px dotted#639E00,1.5px]{\ln x})\right)} \, \bbox[border:2.5px dotted#639E00,1.5px]{\frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx}.$$
We can apply the $u$-substitution method:
$$u \text{-substitution} \qquad \qquad \color{Red}{u = \ln x} \implies \color{Blue}{\mathrm du = \dfrac{1}{x} \mathrm dx}.$$
The integral
$$\mathcal I(x) = {\LARGE \int} \frac{1}{\left(1+\sin^2(\underbrace{\color{Red}{\ln x}}_{\displaystyle u})\right)} \, \underbrace{\color{Blue}{\frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx}}_{\displaystyle \mathrm du}$$
now becomes
$$\mathcal I(u) = {\Large \int} \frac{1}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du. \tag{SUB 1}\label{eq:SUB 1}$$
The integral $\eqref{eq:SUB 1}$ can be computed by the following approach.
Approach: manipulating the expression under integral sign through trigonometric identities.
As per the fundamental trigonometric identity, we can write the numerator of $\eqref{eq:SUB 1}$ as $1 = \sin^2 u + \cos^2 u$. So:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal I(u) &= {\Large \int} \frac{\sin^2 u + \cos^2 u}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du &\text{(using $1 = \sin^2 u + \cos^2 u$)}\\
&= {\Large \int}\frac{\color{orange}{+1} + \sin^2 u + \cos^2 u \color{orange}{-1}}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du &\text{(adding and subtracting $\color{Orange} 1$ at the numerator)}\\
&= {\Large \int} \left(\frac{1+ \sin^2 u}{1+\sin^2 u} + \frac{\cos^2 u -1}{1+\sin^2 u}\right) \mathrm du &\text{(distributing $1+\sin^2 u$)}\\
&= {\Large \int} \left(\frac{\cancel{1+ \sin^2 u}}{\bcancel{1+\sin^2 u}} + \frac{\cos^2 u -1}{1+\sin^2 u}\right) \mathrm du &\text{(canceling $1 + \sin^2 u$ out)}\\
&= {\Large \int} \left(1 + \frac{\cos^2 u -1}{1+ \sin^2 u}\right) \mathrm du &\text{(writing $(1+\sin^2 u)/(1+\sin^2 u)=1$)}\\
&= {\Large \int} \left(1 + \frac{\cos^2 u}{1+\sin^2 u} - \frac{1}{1+\sin^2 u} \right) \mathrm du &\text{(distributing $1+\sin^2 u$)}\\
&= {\Large \int} 1 \, \mathrm du + {\Large \int} \frac{\cos^2 u}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du + {\Large \int} - \frac{1}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du &\text{(by the property of linearity, the integral of the sum of two functions is equal to the sum of the integrals of two functions)}\\
&= {\Large \int} 1 \, \mathrm du + {\Large \int} \frac{\cos^2 u}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du - \underbrace{{\Large \int} \frac{1}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du}_{\displaystyle \mathcal I(u)}&\text{(taking $-$ sign out of integral)}.
\end{align}$$
Noting that on the RHS we have $- \displaystyle \int \frac{1}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du = - \mathcal I(u)$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal I(u) = {\Large \int} 1 \, \mathrm du + {\Large \int} \frac{\cos^2 u}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du - \mathcal I(u) &\iff \mathcal I(u) + \mathcal I(u) = {\Large \int} 1 \, \mathrm du + {\Large \int} \frac{\cos^2 u}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du &\text{(taking $\mathcal I(u)$ from RHS to LHS)}\\
&\iff 2\mathcal I(u) = {\Large \int} 1 \, \mathrm du + {\Large \int} \frac{\cos^2 u}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du &\text{($\mathcal I(u)+\mathcal I(u) = 2 \mathcal I(u)$)}\\
&\iff \mathcal I(u) = \frac{1}{2} \left[\underbrace{{\Large \int} 1 \, \mathrm du}_{\displaystyle \mathcal I_1(u)} + \underbrace{{\Large \int} \frac{\cos^2 u}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du}_{\displaystyle \mathcal I_2(u)}\right], \tag{$\diamondsuit$}\label{eq:diamond} &\text{(dividing both LHS and RHS by $2$)}
\end{align}$$
with $${\displaystyle \mathcal I_1(u) := \int 1 \, \mathrm du}\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$ and
$${\displaystyle \mathcal I_2(u) := \int \frac{\cos^2 u}{1+\sin^2 u} \mathrm du}.\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$
The integral $\mathcal I_1(u)$ is trivially computed as
$$\displaystyle \mathcal I_1(u) := \int 1 \, \mathrm du = u + c_1, \qquad c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$$
To compute the integral $\mathcal I_2(u)$, although both the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions can be found at the denominator and numerator, respectively, a substitution of the type $z = \sin u$ doesn't appear convenient: the cosine appears at the numerator at the second degree ($\cos^2 u$). In contrast, the derivative of $\sin w$ is $\cos w$, at the first degree. One might be tempted to make a substitution of the type $z = \sin^2 u$, but the derivative of the new variable would be $\mathrm dz = 2 \sin u \cos u \, \mathrm du \neq \cos^2 u \, \mathrm du$. Therefore, the strategy to be adopted is to find a trigonometric function (which will be exploited as variable $z$) whose derivative rises at second degree in the numerator.
The sought-after function is $\tan u$, which has derivative equal to:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du} \tan u &= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du} \frac{\sin u}{\cos u} &\text{(using the definition of tangent)}\\
&= \frac{\cos u \cos u - \sin u (-\sin u)}{\cos^2 u} &\text{(applying quotient rule)}\\
&= \frac{\cos^2 u + \sin^2 u}{\cos^2 u} &\text{(multiplying like terms)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\cos^2} u &\text{(using the fundamental trigonometric identity $\sin^2 u + \cos^2 u = 1$)}\\
&:= \color{GoldenRod}{\sec^2 u} &\text{(using the definition of secant)},
\end{align}$$
which is at second order.
Consequently, we manipulate the expression under the integral sign to make only $\sec^2 u \, \mathrm du$ appear in the numerator and an expression as a function of $\tan u$ in the denominator. Dividing both numerator and denominator of $\mathcal I_2(u)$ by $\cos^4 u$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal I_2(u) &= {\Large \int}\dfrac{\dfrac{\cos^2 u}{\color{GoldenRod}{\cos^4 u}}}{\dfrac{1+\sin^2 u}{\color{GoldenRod}{\cos^4 u}}} \, \mathrm du &\text{(dividing both numerator and denominator by $\cos^4 u$)}\\ \\
&= {\Large \int}\dfrac{\dfrac{\cos^{\cancel{2}} u}{\cos^{\cancel{4} 2} u}}{\dfrac{1+\sin^2 u}{\cos^4 u}} \, \mathrm du &\text{(canceling $\cos^2 u$ out)}\\ \\
&= {\Large \int} \frac{\dfrac{1}{\cos^2 u}}{\dfrac{1+\sin^2 u}{\cos^4 u}} \mathrm du &\text{(rewriting the simplified expression)}\\ \\
&= {\Large \int} \frac{\color{GoldenRod}{\sec^2 u}}{\dfrac{1+\sin^2 u}{\cos^4 u}} \mathrm du &\text{(using the definition of secant)}\\ \\
&= {\Large \int} \frac{\sec^2 u}{\dfrac{1}{\cos^4 u} + \dfrac{\sin^2 u}{\cos^4 u}} \mathrm du &\text{(distributing $\cos^4 u$ at the denominator)}\\ \\
&= {\Large \int} \frac{\sec^2 u}{\dfrac{1}{(\cos^2 u)^2} + \dfrac{\sin^2 u}{(\cos^2 u)^2}} &\text{(writing $\cos^4 u = (\cos^2 u)^2)$)}\mathrm du \\ \\
&= {\Large \int} \frac{\sec^2 u}{\dfrac{1}{(\cos^2 u)^2} + \dfrac{\sin^2 u}{(\cos^2 u)(\cos^2 u)}}&\text{(writing $(\cos^2 u)^2 = (\cos^2 u)(\cos^2 u)$)} \mathrm du \\ \\
&= {\Large \int} \frac{\sec^2 u}{\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{(\cos^2 u)^2}}_{\displaystyle (1 + \tan^2 u)^2} + \underbrace{\dfrac{\sin^2 u}{\cos^2 u}}_{\displaystyle \tan^2 u} \,\,\, \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{\cos^2 u}}_{\displaystyle 1+\tan^2 u}} \mathrm du \\ \\
&= {\Large \int} \frac{\sec^2 u}{(1+\tan^2 u)^2 + \tan^2 u \, (1+\tan^2 u)} \mathrm du &\text{(using $(\cos^2 u)^2 = (1 + \tan^2 u)^2$ and $\sin^2 u/\cos^2 u = \tan^2 u$)}\\
&={\Large \int} \frac{\sec^2 u}{(1+\tan^2 u)(1+\tan^2 u)+\tan^2 u \, (1+\tan^2 u)} \mathrm du &\text{(writing $(1+\tan^2 u)^2 = (1+\tan^2 u)(1+\tan^2 u)$)}\\
&={\Large \int} \frac{\sec^2 u}{(1+\tan^2 u)(1+\tan^2 u + \tan^2 u)} \mathrm du &\text{(total factoring $1+\tan^2 u$ out)}\\
&={\Large \int} \frac{\sec^2 u}{(1+\tan^2 u)(1+2\tan^2 u)} \mathrm du &\text{(adding like terms)}.
\end{align}$$
So, the new expression for the integral $\mathcal I_2(u)$ is
$$\mathcal I_2(u) = {\Large \int} \frac{\sec^2 u}{(1+\tan^2 u)(1+2\tan^2 u)} \mathrm du.$$
At this point, it is appropriate to make the substitution $z=\tan u$, as argued above:
$$z \text{-substitution} \qquad \color{Purple}{z = \tan u} \implies \color{brown}{\mathrm dz = \sec^2 u \, \mathrm du}.$$
The integral
$$\mathcal I_2(u) = {\Large \int} \frac{1}{(1+ \underbrace{\color{Purple}{\tan^2 u}}_{\displaystyle z^2})(1+2 \, \underbrace{\color{Purple}{\tan^2 u}}_{\displaystyle z^2})} \underbrace{\color{brown}{\sec^2 u \, \mathrm du}}_{\displaystyle \mathrm dz}$$
now becomes
$$\mathcal I_2(z) = {\Large \int} \frac{1}{(z^2+1)(2z^2+1)} \, \mathrm dz. \tag{SUB 2}\label{eq:SUB 2}$$
Using partial fraction decomposition, we obtain:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(z^2+1)(2z^2+1)} &= \frac{Az+B}{z^2+1} + \frac{Cz+D}{2z^2+1} \, \qquad \text{for some $A, B, C, D \in \mathbb{R}$} \\
\frac{1}{(z^2+1)(2z^2+1)} &= \frac{(Az+B)(2z^2+1)+(Cz+D)(z^2+1)}{(z^2+1)(2z^2+1)} &\text{(writing the RHS as a fraction by involving lowest common multiple)}\\
\frac{1}{\bcancel{(z^2+1)(2z^2+1)}} &= \frac{(Az+B)(2z^2+1)+(Cz+D)(z^2+1)}{\bcancel{(z^2+1)(2z^2+1)}} &\text{(canceling the common denominator out)}\\
1 &= 2Az^3+Az+2Bz^2+B+Cz^3+Cz+Dz^2+D &\text{(multiplying terms inside round brackets)}\\
\color{Blue}{0z^3}+\color{Purple}{0z^2}+\color{Fuchsia}{0z}+\color{Red}{1} &=
\color{Blue}{(2A+C)z^3} +\color{Purple}{(2B+D)z^2} + \color{Fuchsia}{(A+C)z}+\color{Red}{(B+D)} &\text{(comparing terms with the same degree)}\\
\color{Blue}{\underline{0}} z^3+\color{Purple}{\underline{0}} z^2+\color{Fuchsia}{\underline{0}}z+\color{Red}{\underline{1}} &=
\color{Blue}{\underline{(2A+C)}}z^3 +\color{Purple}{\underline{(2B+D)}}z^2 + \color{Fuchsia}{\underline{(A+C)}}z+\color{Red}{\underline{(B+D)}} &\text{(comparing coefficients of the terms between LHS and RHS)},
\end{align}$$
from which
$$\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
0 = 2A+C \\
0 = 2B+D \\
0 = A+C \\
1 = B+D
\vphantom{\frac{0}{0}}
\end{cases} &\iff 
\begin{cases}
C = -2A \\
D = -2B \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} \\
A+C = 0 \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} \\
B+D = 1 \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}}
\end{cases} \\ &\iff
\begin{cases}
C = -2A \\
D = -2B \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} \\
C = -A \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} \\
D= 1-B \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}}
\end{cases} \\ &\iff
\begin{cases}
-2A = -A \\
-2B = 1-B \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} \\
C=-A \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} \\
D = -2B \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}}
\end{cases}\\ &\iff
\begin{cases}
0 = A \\
0 = 1+B \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} \\
C = -A \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} \\
D = -2B \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}}
\end{cases}\\ &\iff
\begin{cases}
A=0 \\
B=-1 \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} \\
C=0 \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} \\
D=2 \vphantom{\frac{0}{0}}
\end{cases}.
\end{align}$$
So, substituting $A=0, B=-1, C=0, D=2$ into the expression under integral sign yields:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(z^2+1)(2z^2+1)} &= \frac{Az+B}{z^2+1} + \frac{Cz+D}{2z^2+1} \\
&= \frac{0z-1}{z^2+1} + \frac{0z+2}{2z^2+1} \\
&= \frac{-1}{z^2+1}+\frac{2}{2z^2+1}.
\end{align}$$
Plugging this expression into $\eqref{eq:SUB 2}$:
$$\begin{align}
I_2 (z) &= {\Large \int} \left(\frac{-1}{(z^2+1)} + \frac{2}{2z^2+1}\right)\mathrm dz \\
&= {\Large \int} \frac{-1}{(z^2+1)} \mathrm dz + {\Large \int} \frac{2}{(2z^2+1)} \mathrm dz &\text{(by the property of linearity, the integral of the sum of two functions is equal to the sum of the integrals of two functions)}\\
&= - {\Large \int}\frac{1}{z^2+1} \mathrm dz + 2 {\Large \int} \frac{1}{2z^2+1} \mathrm dz &\text{(taking $-$ sign and $2$ out of integrals)}\\
&= - \arctan z + \mathcal C + 2 {\Large \int} \frac{\color{Red}{\sqrt 2}}{\color{Red}{\sqrt 2}} \frac{1}{(\sqrt 2 z)^2 +1} \mathrm dz, \qquad \mathcal C \in \mathbb R &\text{(computing the first integral and multiplying both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt 2$)}\\
&= - \arctan z + \mathcal C + \frac{2}{\sqrt 2}{\Large \int}\frac{\sqrt 2}{(\sqrt 2 \, z)^2 +1} \mathrm dz, \qquad \mathcal C \in \mathbb R &\text{(taking $1/\sqrt 2$ out of integral)}\\
&= - \arctan z + \mathcal C + \frac{\cancel{\sqrt 2} \sqrt 2}{\bcancel{\sqrt 2}} \arctan (\sqrt 2 \, z) + \mathfrak C, \qquad \mathcal C, \mathfrak C \in \mathbb R &\text{(computing the second integral, writing $2$ as $\sqrt 2 \sqrt 2$ and canceling $\sqrt 2$ out)}\\
&= - \arctan z + \sqrt 2 \arctan (\sqrt 2 \, z) + \underbrace{\mathcal C + \mathfrak C}_{\displaystyle c_2}, \qquad \mathcal C, \mathfrak C \in \mathbb R &\text{(setting the constant $\mathcal C + \mathfrak C = c_2$)}\\
&= - \arctan z + \sqrt 2 \arctan (\sqrt 2 \, z) + c_2, \qquad c_2 \in \mathbb R.
\end{align}$$
So, the integral is $$\mathcal I_2(z) = - \arctan z + \sqrt 2 \arctan (\sqrt 2 \, z) + c_2, \qquad c_2 \in \mathbb R.$$
Resubstituting $z = \tan u$, we obtain:
$$\mathcal I_2(u) = - \underbrace{\arctan (\tan u)}_{\displaystyle u} + \sqrt 2 \arctan (\sqrt 2 \, \tan u) + c_2, \qquad c_2 \in \mathbb R.$$
So, we have
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal I_1(u) &= u + c_1, \qquad c_1 \in \mathbb R \tag{$\spadesuit$}\label{eq:spade}\\
\mathcal I_2(u) &= -u +\sqrt 2 \arctan (\sqrt 2 \, \tan u) + c_2, \qquad c_2 \in \mathbb R \tag{$\clubsuit$}\label{eq:club}
\end{align}$$
Plugging $\eqref{eq:spade}$ and $\eqref{eq:club}$ into $\eqref{eq:diamond}$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal I (u) &= \frac{1}{2}\left[u-u+\sqrt 2 \arctan (\sqrt 2 \, \tan u)\right] + \underbrace{c_1 + c_2}_{\displaystyle c}, \qquad c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb R &\text{(setting the constant $c_1+c_2 = c$)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[\cancel{u}\cancel{-u}+\sqrt 2 \arctan (\sqrt 2 \, \tan u)\right] + c, \qquad c \in \mathbb R &\text{(canceling $u$ out)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 \sqrt 2} \sqrt 2 \arctan(\sqrt 2 \, \tan u) &\text{(writing $2$ as $\sqrt 2 \sqrt 2$)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\bcancel{\sqrt 2} \sqrt 2} \cancel{\sqrt 2} \arctan(\sqrt 2 \, \tan u)&\text{(canceling $\sqrt 2$ out)},
\end{align}$$
from which
$$\mathcal I (u) = \frac{\arctan (\sqrt 2 \, \tan u)}{\sqrt 2} + c, \qquad c \in \mathbb{R}\tag{FI}\label{eq:FI}$$
Resubstituting $u = \ln x$ into $\eqref{eq:FI}$:
$$\bbox[10px,#f3ffff, border:5px outset #982543]{\mathcal I = {\Large \int} \frac{1}{x \, \left(1+\sin^2(\ln x)\right)} \mathrm dx = \frac{\arctan \Big(\sqrt 2 \, \tan \left(\ln x \right)\Big)}{\sqrt 2} + c, \qquad c \in \mathbb{R}}$$

Very good also in MathJaX.
